# Is there a significant computational time difference between == and !=?

Tags: performance, big-o, calculation

The question is pretty simple. When checking the equality of a variable with another variable, is there a significant computational time difference between being equal or not? Actually my question covers all programming languages, but I can expand the question with !== and === specific to JS.

It is a discussion topic about computational time difference of equality.

Comment: Generally speaking, it's reasonable to expect `if (x != y) {foo();} else {bar();}` to be equivalent to `if (x == y) {bar();} else {foo();}`.  That said, in C++ it's possible for the implementer of a class to define the behavior of the `==` and `!=` operators independently of each other, so a sufficiently demented C++ developer could write a `==` operator that is `O(1)` and a `!=` operator that is `O(N^3)`, if he chose to.

Answer (score 1):

In most programming languages (C, C++, Java, Python, JS) there is **no significant computational time difference** between the `==` (equality) and `!=` (inequality) operators.

Time complexity of these operators is **constant time** (O(1)). The comparison is **direct comparison of the values**, which does not depend on the size or complexity of the values being compared.

However, it's important to note that the performance of the `==` and `!=` operators can depend on the type of values being compared.

**For primitive types**, such as integers or booleans, the comparison is straightforward and efficient.

However, for **complex objects** or reference types, the `==` and `!=` operators compare the references (memory addresses) instead of the actual contents of the objects. Sometimes the comparison time can vary based on the complexity of the object's state.

So, for most simple data types and **primitive values**, the computational time difference between `==` and `!=` is **negligible**.

However, for **complex objects** or **reference types**, the performance can be influenced by the internal implementation of the comparison or the `equals()` method.

For JS, `===` checks for value and type equality while `!==` it checks same for inequality. So, there is two comparison for both operators, one is for type-checking and another is for value. So, there is no big difference in time complexity between these operators.

Comment: Several of your recent answers here appear likely to have been entirely or partially written by AI (e.g., ChatGPT).  Please be aware that [posting AI-generated content is not allowed here](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/421831). If you used an AI tool to assist with any answer, I would encourage you to delete it.  Thanks!

Comment: **Readers should review this answer carefully and critically, as AI-generated information often contains fundamental errors and misinformation.** If you observe quality issues and/or have reason to believe that this answer was generated by AI, please leave feedback accordingly. The moderation team can use your help to identify quality issues.